# Difference between Dalvik Bridge Function and Dalvik Native Function call?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between Dalvik Bridge Function and Dalvik Native Function call in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words ,

Android is a Linux based OS, runs a linux kernel (Dalvik VM). It can run C based program more efficiently than any kind of java based executable. Java based executable is easy to build but is heavy w.r.t performance and space requirements.

C language based programs are called Native codes, Dalvik Native codes are nothing but C programs compiled for running in Dalvik VM.

There is a bridge that is created between the Nativeness and Java application dev for android using JNI (NDK). This allows us to benifit more from the C based code.

In other words Dalvik Native Function represents the API that is most likely to expose should JNI performance be deemed insufficient.  The Bridge version is used as an optimization for a few high-volume Object calls, and should generally not be used as we may drop support for it at some point.
[Reference](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/dalvik/vm/native/)